# x.shape[0] vs x[0].shape in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let say, I have an array with

`x.shape = (10,1024)`

when I try to print x[0].shape

```
x[0].shape
```

it prints 1024

and when I print x.shape[0]

```
x.shape[0]
```

it prints 10

I know it's a silly question, and maybe there is another question like this, but can someone explain it to me ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`x` is a 2D array, which can also be looked upon as an array of 1D arrays, having 10 rows and 1024 columns. `x[0]` is the first 1D sub-array which has 1024 elements (there are 10 such 1D sub-arrays in `x`), and `x[0].shape` gives the shape of that sub-array, which happens to be a 1-tuple - `(1024, )`.

On the other hand, `x.shape` is a 2-tuple which represents the shape of `x`, which in this case is `(10, 1024)`. `x.shape[0]` gives the first element in that tuple, which is `10`.

Here's a demo with some smaller numbers, which should hopefully be easier to understand.

```
x = np.arange(36).reshape(-1, 9)
x

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
       [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]])

x[0]
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

x[0].shape
(9,)

x.shape
(4, 9)

x.shape[0]
4
```

Answer (score 9):

`x[0].shape` will give the Length of 1st row of an array. `x.shape[0]` will give the number of rows in an array. In your case it will give output 10. If you will type `x.shape[1]`, it will print out the number of columns i.e 1024. If you would type `x.shape[2]`, it will give an error, since we are working on a 2-d array and we are out of index. Let me explain you all the uses of 'shape' with a simple example by taking a 2-d array of zeros of dimension 3x4.

```
import numpy as np
#This will create a 2-d array of zeroes of dimensions 3x4
x = np.zeros((3,4))
print(x)
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]

#This will print the First Row of the 2-d array
x[0]
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])

#This will Give the Length of 1st row
x[0].shape
(4,)

#This will Give the Length of 2nd row, verified that length of row is showing same 
x[1].shape
(4,)

#This will give the dimension of 2-d Array 
x.shape
(3, 4)

# This will give the number of rows is 2-d array 
x.shape[0]
3

# This will give the number of columns is 2-d array 
x.shape[1]
3

# This will give the number of columns is 2-d array 
x.shape[1]
4

# This will give an error as we have a 2-d array and we are asking value for an index 
out of range
x.shape[2]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-4b202d084bc7> in <module>()
----> 1 x.shape[2]

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Answer (score 2):

`x[0].shape` gives you the length of the first row. `x.shape[0]` gives you the  first component of the dimensions of 'x', 1024 rows by 10 columns.

Answer (score 0):

`x.shape[0]` will give the number of rows in an array.

`x[0]` is 1st row of `x` so `x[0].shape` will provide the length of 1st row.